# Using Github Copilot with Regular Vim

Tags: vim9

I'm not finding much out there in terms of docs about using copilot with regular vim (everything I've come across is about using it with nvim / neovim)

The [copilot.vim](https://github.com/github/copilot.vim) docs mention it should support newer versions of vim "9.0.0162 or newer", so I've built vim from source and installed it, ran `:Copilot setup` successfully, and it seems to be partially working. However it doesn't provide any suggestions inline while typing.

`:Copilot status` reports: "Copilot: Neovim 0.6 required to support ghost text" so I'm guessing there is a problem with the parts that show the inline preview.

If I open the `:Copilot panel` I can see it's suggestions and accept them with the enter button, but it's unwieldy to use via the separate panel.

So are there any guides or anwers about how to get this working better in regular vim? Thank you

Comment: You might be able to make it work with some relatively new (experimental?) features of Vim's text properties that are similar to "ghost text" (_i.e._, virtual text)

Comment: Thank you for the tip; it led me to https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/7553 and to double check that I had the required patch 162 which apparently I did not, and the inline virtual text is now working

Comment: Moreover, Copilot is a paid service (if not right now, it's gonna be). Why not get your money's worth and ask their help desk?

Comment: I preferred to ask on here, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Inline suggestions (AKA "virtual text" or "ghost text") require vim version 9.0.0162 (patch 162); use `vim --version` to see vim's version and installed patches, ex.:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Sep  8 2022 22:06:47)
Included patches: 1-420
```

and also require vim to be compiled with the `textprop` feature